# Tcl formatting :how to display multiple rows and columns with formatting

Tags: scripting, tcl

I need to print the following based on the variable n.

Example: if n=2
I need to print:

```
1. -3 0
2.  3 0
3.  0 -3
4.  0 3
```

If n=3
I need to print:

```
1. -3 0 0   
2. 3  0 0
3. 0 -3 0
4. 0  3 0
5. 0  0 -3
6. 0  0 3
```

If n=4, I need to print:

```
1. -3 0 0 0
2. 3 0 0 0
3. 0 -3 0 0
4. 0 3  0 0 
5. 0 0 -3 0
6. 0 0 3  0
7. 0 0 0 -3
8. 0 0 0  3
```

Comment: Take a look at [for](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/for.htm), [format](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm), [if](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/if.htm), and [puts](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/puts.htm).

Comment: Probably also `incr`. And I'm not sure if the preceding counter is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing you need here is `format`. It's great for producing output in fixed-width text form. Now, writing the format-items for a `format` string is an art (very closely related to doing the same for `sprintf()` in C) that quite a few people lack nowadays, but something like this is what you want were you just doing the `n == 4` case:

```
puts [format "%d. %2d %2d %2d" $count $c1 $c2 $c3]
```

In this case, however, you've got a more complex problem because you have a variable number of fields. That makes things trickier; you're probably best building things up piecemeal with the help of a procedure to do the formatting of a single line:

```
proc generateLine {n i} {
    set line [format "%d." $i]
    for {set x 1} {$x <= $n} {incr x} {
        # Double-ternary conditional operator
        set v [expr {$i == $x*2-1 ? -3 : $i == $x*2 ? 3 : 0}]
        append line [format " %2d" $v]
    }
    return $line
}
```

Now that we have that, the rest of the program is simple enough:

```
# Assume that the n variable has been set already
for {set i 1} {$i <= $n*2} {incr i} {
    puts [generateLine $n $i]
}
```

Very often in programming, it's easiest if you split a program into several pieces with sensible boundaries between. Knowing where to split is something that you get better at with experience, but very often the split is in the right place if you can give a sensible name to the split out piece. For example, above I saw that I wanted to do some work for each line and some work to iterate over all the lines needed; that was the obvious place to break things apart and make a procedure, `generateLine`. The outer part is also quite nameable (perhaps `generateListOfLines`?) but that isn't so important here.